# Extract dataframe-entries based on date

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has the following form

```
 V1   V2    V3          V4
999   53 2015-07-02     2
999   53 2011-07-03     3
998   56 2015-03-08     4
998   56 2011-03-18     5
998   58 2014-12-26     6
998   57 2016-05-21     8
998   57 2015-04-12     9
998   58 2013-09-29     10
997   63 2013-09-28     19
997   63 2014-08-21     20
```

Note that duplicates **always** appear in columns `V1` and `V2` ( `(999, 53)` and `(998,56)` and so on). Also note that `V3` is a date. So the two entries making up a duplicate appear at two different times.

I would like to create two dataframes from the above dataset, one with the **early** entries of the duplicates and one with the **old** entrires. I.e., I would like to end up with the following two dataframes

the "**old**"

```
999   53 2011-07-03     3
998   56 2011-03-18     5
998   57 2015-04-12     9
998   58 2013-09-29     10
997   63 2013-09-28     19
```

and "**early**"

```
999   53 2015-07-02     2
998   56 2015-03-08     4
998   58 2014-12-26     6
998   57 2016-05-21     8
997   63 2014-08-21     20
```

I can of course use two `for`-loops for this, but my data is quite large so it will be inefficient. Are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: what if you have 3 duplicates of the same values?

Comment: @mtoto that will never happend. we will only have unique entries of two (with different dates), never more or less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jealie pointed out in comments, for these solutions, `df` would have to be sorted on `V3` first.

```
df = df[order(df$V3),]
```

1. You could just split at once

   `split(df, duplicated(df[,1:2]))`
2. OR use `duplicated` with `V1` and `V2` to subset separately

   `df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),]`
   `df[duplicated(df[,1:2]),]`
3. OR Use `ave` to determine if a duplicate pair is appearing for the first time or second time and subset directly.

   `df[ave(seq_along(df$V1), paste(df$V1, df$V2, sep = "-"), FUN = seq_along) ==1,]`
   `df[ave(seq_along(df$V1), paste(df$V1, df$V2, sep = "-"), FUN = seq_along) == 2,]`

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(V1 = c(999L, 999L, 998L, 998L, 998L, 998L, 998L, 
998L, 997L, 997L), V2 = c(53L, 53L, 56L, 56L, 58L, 57L, 57L, 
58L, 63L, 63L), V3 = c("2015-07-02", "2011-07-03", "2015-03-08", 
"2011-03-18", "2014-12-26", "2016-05-21", "2015-04-12", "2013-09-29", 
"2013-09-28", "2014-08-21"), V4 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 19L, 20L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: For these solutions to work, one would need to `sort` on V3 first.

Comment: @d.b In the first method using `split`, what is the proper way to assign each part to a dataframe? using `df <- split(df, duplicated(df[,1:2]))` gives me the parameters `FALSE` and `TRUE`, but I can't get the dataframes by `df$TRUE` and `df$FALSE`

Comment: @BillyJean, `$'FALSE'` and `$'TRUE'`

Answer (score 3):

As long as you only have pairs, this will work.

```
# get the positions of the rows sorted by V2 and then V3
myOrd <- with(df, order(V2, V3))

# Keep the first observation of each pair (early)
df[myOrd[c(TRUE, FALSE)],]
   V1 V2         V3 V4
2 999 53 2011-07-03  3
4 998 56 2011-03-18  5
7 998 57 2015-04-12  9
8 998 58 2013-09-29 10
9 997 63 2013-09-28 19

# Keep the second observation of each pair (late)
df[myOrd[c(FALSE, TRUE)],]
    V1 V2         V3 V4
1  999 53 2015-07-02  2
3  998 56 2015-03-08  4
6  998 57 2016-05-21  8
5  998 58 2014-12-26  6
10 997 63 2014-08-21 20
```

Here, `order` is used to find the positions of the sorted observations. Then `c(TRUE, FALSE)` and `c(FALSE, TRUE)` are used to extract the desired rows.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done very efficiently using `data.table`:

```
require('data.table') # if needed, install before with install.packages('data.table') 

dt = data.table(your_data_frame)

dt[, type := ifelse(V3==min(V3),'old','new'), keyby=c('V1','V2')]
```

This will create a new column containing the status of your input:

```
> dt
     V1 V2         V3 V4 type
 1: 997 63 2013-09-28 19  old
 2: 997 63 2014-08-21 20  new
 3: 998 56 2015-03-08  4  new
 4: 998 56 2011-03-18  5  old
 5: 998 57 2016-05-21  8  new
 6: 998 57 2015-04-12  9  old
 7: 998 58 2014-12-26  6  new
 8: 998 58 2013-09-29 10  old
 9: 999 53 2015-07-02  2  new
10: 999 53 2011-07-03  3  old
```

And you can then subset your data using `dt[type == 'new']` or `dt[type == 'old']`.